# Is there anyway to run python script asynchronously in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I want to run python script in airflow. To achieve the same I am triggering script using airflow bash operator like below.

```
sub_dag = BashOperator(
task_id='execute_dependent_dag',
bash_command='python myscript.py',
dag=dag,
trigger_rule="all_success")
```

However I want it to be triggered asynchronously. Currently it is waiting for script to get finish. I used **&** as well as **nohup** to make it run but it didn't work.

Let me know if there is any other way to run it asynchronously.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I believe extending `BashOperator` to remove [`wait()` call](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L124) would make that happen with the downside that errors would go silently undetected
- Alternatively if the `python` *script / code* in question can be *`import`ed* into your `Airflow` *project*, you could try doing the same [with `PythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L103) through [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (or a variety of other ways)

Also if you want to get your hands dirty, have a look at [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2dadee7a248442012e835eeaad3f21f698d0642b/tests/core.py#L890)